# programmatically create WinSSHD virtual accounts

Tags: api

We're using WinSSHD as an SFTP server, and I'd like a way for the users of my ASP.NET C# web app to create a new virtual account on the server.  (Each user of the web app has multiple partners who will need individual FTP accounts, so it's not convenient for me to just manually create them every time.)  Each of these virtual accounts needs to have a mount point so that its route path points to a different physical path.

Presently I only know how to do this sort of thing in the WinSSHD Control Panel.  Is there some sort of API for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.  I ended up doing something like this:

```
// This Guid is the uuid of the coclass in WinsshdCfgManip.idl (depends on your WinSSHD version)
dynamic config = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("A3E7581A-5182-41C4-9AFD-2DFF07F06167"), server, true));

config.SetSite("WinSSHD");
config.LockWinsshdSettings();
config.LoadWinsshdSettings();

config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.virtAccount """ + username + @"""");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.virtPassword.Set """ + password + @"""");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.group ""Virtual Users""");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.useDefaultWinAccount false");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.winDomain """ + winDomain + @"""");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.winAccount """ + winAccount + @"""");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.loginAllowed yes");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.passwordAuth required");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.permitRemoteAdmin no");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.mapRemoteHomeDir no");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.allowSessionJobBreakaway no");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.permitTerminalShell no");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.permitExecRequests no");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.permitSftp yes");
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.sfsMap.useDefaultSfsMap false");

// Backslashes in rootPath need to be escaped as \\ for ProcessInstruction
// E.g.:
// string rootPath = @"C:\\FTP\\MyFtpFolder";
config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.New.sfsMap.mountPoints.1.realRootPath """ + rootPath + @"""");

config.ProcessInstruction(@"access.virtAccounts.NewCommit");

config.SaveWinsshdSettings(1);
config.UnlockWinsshdSettings();
```